# Formulario de contacto para página web con PHP

Tags: php, css, phpmyadmin, web

Tengo un trabajo de la uni y necesito ayuda para hacer un formulario de contacto con `php` y `mysql` y estoy muy perdido. El código del formulario de contacto es el siguiente:

````
</section>
    <div class="lets_touch_main">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="input_main">`introducir el código aquí`
                   <div class="container">
                      <form action="action.php">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <input type="text" class="email-bt" placeholder="Nombre" name="Name" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <input type="text" class="email-bt" placeholder="Email" name="Email" required>
                        </div>
                        <form action="/action_page.php">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <textarea class="massage-bt" placeholder="Mensaje" rows="5" id="comment" name="text" requierd></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                      </form>
                   </div> 
                   <div class="send_btn">
                    <a href="#">Enviar</a>
                   </div>                   
                </div>
            </div>```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un formulario de contacto utilizando HTML, PHP, MYSQL.

Mírate bien los comentarios que he hecho en el código para que veas los errores.

```
<!-- Esto es un comentario en HTML -->
```

Tu código corregido:

```
  <div class="lets_touch_main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="input_main">`introducir el código aquí`
               <div class="container">

                  <form action="action.php"> <!-- ESTO ABRE EL FORMULARIO --> 
                    <div class="form-group">
                     <input type="text" class="email-bt" placeholder="Nombre" name="Name" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" class="email-bt" placeholder="Email" name="Email" required>
                    </div>
                    <form action="/action_page.php"> <!-- NO ENTIENDO PORQUE ABRES OTRO FORMULARIO, MANTÉN TODO EN EL MISMO FORMULARIO, SI LUEGO QUIERES GUARDAR LOS DATOS EN SITIOS DIFERENTES, PHP HACE ESO POR TI --> 

                        <div class="form-group">
                          <textarea class="massage-bt" placeholder="Mensaje" rows="5" id="comment" name="text" required></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </form> <!-- LO MISMO, SOLO UN FORMULARIO MEJOR -->
                  </form> 
               </div> 
               <div class="send_btn">
                <a href="#">Enviar</a> <!-- AQUÍ PARA ENVIAR UN FORMULARIO DEBES UTILIZARLA ETIQUETA <button> CON UN SUBMIT, LA ETIQUETA <a> ES PARA ENLACES --> 
               </div>                   
            </div>
        </div>
```

Después de haber leído los comentarios que te escrito arriba, quédate con:

-En tu caso abre solo un `<form>`.

-Etiqueta `<button>` para enviar, no la `<a>`. Debe estar dentro del `<form>`

Tu código HTML entonces quedaría así:

```
<div class="lets_touch_main">
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="input_main">
        <div class="container">
               <p> Formulario HTML, PHP Y MYSQL</p> 

                  <form action="action.php">
                       <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="email-bt" placeholder="Nombre" name="Name" required>
                       </div>

                       <div class="form-group">
                   <input type="text" class="email-bt" placeholder="Email" name="Email" required>
                       </div>

                       <div class="form-group">
                   <textarea class="massage-bt" placeholder="Mensaje" rows="5" id="comment" name="text" required></textarea>
                        </div>

                   <button type="submit" class="send_btn" >Guardar</button>
                 </form>
                  
     </div> 
     </div>
     </div>
     </div> 
     </div>
     </div>
```

Vale, después debemos utilizar `php`, un lenguaje de cara al servidor que nos ayudará a guardar los datos en la base de datos.

Mírate bien los comentarios que he escrito para que comprendas que pasa en cada paso.
Los comentarios en php tienen este formato.

```
//Esto es un comentario en PhP
```

```html
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { //Recoge los datos que el usuario a insertado en el POST
    
  //Declaramos las variables del servidor 
      $server = "localhost"; //Ahora trabajamos con el localhost
    $name = "root";
    $password = "";

    //Inserta los datos en variables para que después utilizarlas y limpiamos los tres campos
    $u_name = filter_var($_POST["user_name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
  
    $u_email = filter_var($_POST["user_email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
  
    $u_text = filter_var($_POST["user_text"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


//Comprobamos que no esten vacíos o mal escritos
    if (empty($u_name)){
        echo "Campo vacío";
    }
    if (empty($u_email) || !filter_var($u_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        echo"email inválido";
    }
        
    if (empty($u_text)){
        echo "Campo vacío";
    }   

    //Conectar con el MYQSL base de datos
  // Utilizamos pdo
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=tubasededatos", $name, $password);
    
    $statement = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tutabladedatos (name, email, text) VALUES(:name, :email, :text)"); // Preparamos el INSERT 
    
//Preparamos los Bind_param, puedes ver cómo hacemos uso de las variables que antes hemos declarado
    $statement->bind_param(':name', $u_name); 
    $statement->bind_param(':email', $u_email);
    $statement->bind_param(':text', $u_text);
    if($statement->execute()){
        print "Hola " . $u_name . "!, esto funciona!";
    }else{
        print $conn->error; //marca error
    }
}
?>
```

Vale, recuerda de tendrás que crear la base de datos respectiva para insertar los datos del `form`. Te recomiendo utilizar `Phpmyadmin`.

Conclusión:

-Recuerda la estructura de un `form`

-El PHP hace la función de guardar los datos en la base de datos, busca información sobre `pdo`, `variables`, limpiar inputs, insertar datos con `pdo`, etc.

-I luego infórmate sobre `Phpmyadmin`, una herramienta para bases de datos que te ayudará bastante.

Te recomiendo que busques información o tutoriales en internet sobre formularios, actualmente hay una gran variedad de formas.

Enlaces utilizados, te recomiendo que los veas también.

https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/07/creating-simple-form-using-php-and-mysql
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/custom-php-mysql-contact-form/
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/signup-form-using-php-and-mysql-database/

Answer (score 0):

No es complicado. Te falta crear el archivo php, supongo que tienes una tabla para los datos en la base de datos, sino créala.
Supongo que se trata de recoger datos y guardarlo en la base.

1.Conecta con la base de datos.
2.En el archivo php (action.php) lees los datos enviados desde el formulario con el array $_POST['Name'], $_POST['Email'], $_POST['comment'].
3: Filtrar los datos recibidos para verificar la seguridad y eliminar caracteres no aceptables
4: comprobar que el registro no existe
5. Inserta los datos en la base de datos.
6. Muestra un mensaje de agradecimiento o algo así.

Esto es lo mínimo. Como ves solo php y MySql